# OpenCV 2.2 and multi-CPUs - Is opencv_haartraining.exe multithreaded?

Tags: opencv

I built OpenCV 2.2 on VS 2010.  Enabled TBB 3 support.  I ensured all the projects had the right tbb lib directories, and tbb.lib listed as a dependency.

Verified it by hiding tbb.dll - sure enough haartraining.exe complained it needed it.

Ok - my question.  I'm running a big training set on a 16 core machine, and haartraining is pegging only one of the CPUs, the other 15 are idle.

What am I doing wrong?  I don't see any flags on the exe to trigger MP.

One other question - I included IPP, as well.  That is statically linked, right (meaning I don't need to install IPP on the box I'm running this on?)?  I suppose it must be otherwise it wouldn't be running.

Thanks!

edit:  two other bits of info:  1) Task manager says opencv_haartraining.exe has only 1 thread.  2) this is a 32-bit build running on a 64-bit version of windows XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If built with TBB then TBB.dll is needed - it doesn't mean the specific function is using TBB.

To see which functions are TBB enabled you need to look at the code, or follow the opencV minutes - eg http://pr.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCVMeetingNotes/Minutes%202010-03-30

Comment: thanks - I thought I saw "HAVE_TBB" #defines in the haar code, but I didn't look too closely.  It's probably not MT...