# OpenCV traincascade with multithreading

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I want to train haar cascade by opencv_traincascade.

after

```
opencv_traincascade -data result/apple/ -vec samples/sample.vec -bg negatives.dat -minHitRate 0.999 -mode ALL -numPos 2000 -numNeg 1500 -precalcValBufSize 2000 -precalcIdxBufSize 2000
```

I saw that only one core is loaded. What can I do to quickly train the cascade? If I need to recompile OpenCV with some options please show me how to do it. Thank you!

UPD:
Found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151558/opencv-2-2-and-multi-cpus-is-opencv-haartraining-exe-multithreaded). There is a new question: how to set up OpenCV with flag `HAVE_TBB`? And will it help me? Which version of [IPP](https://registrationcenter.intel.com/RegCenter/NComForm.aspx?ProductID=1452) I can use with OpenCV 2.4.3?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my English.
I found the answer to my question.

*Tested on xubuntu 12-10 with IPP 7.1 for intel64 and Opencv 2.4.3*

To use IPP&&TBB with OpenCV you should download and install them from the [official site](https://registrationcenter.intel.com/RegCenter/NComForm.aspx?ProductID=1452)

**ia32 for 32-bit architecture, intel64 for 64 bit!**

After you should compile OpenCv by this command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_IPP=ON -D IPP_H_PATH=/opt/intel/ipp/include/ -D WITH_TBB=ON ..
```

**Check output after cmake!**

```
make
sudo make install
```